# iPhone Accelerometer Values

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer

My question is about the iPhone accelerometer.  Does the accelerometer measure acceleration or movement of the iPhone?  What I mean is if I hold the iPhone and go from 0mph to 60mph, I would expect the measure of acceleration to increase in value from 0 to 60, but once I reach 60, I expect the value to return to 0 since I am "no longer accelerating" but am moving at a constant speed.  Now if the accelerometer measure motion, I would expect it to register 0 to 60 and continue to provide a change in value as I move forward at 60mph.  Sorry, I looked at a few books, programmed some code (values seemed to small to give a recognizable result over short distances or speeds), and a lot of web searches, and I am trying to get an answer to this question.

Thanx!

Comment: Think of it as the same thing as measuring "G-force".

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

- The accelerometer never reads zero because gravity is always with us and is an acceleration (and a good thing too). If it ever reads 0 you are in deep doo-doo - you have been cast adrift in space, or else you are in free-fall plunging towards the ground.
- When you go from 0 to 60, acceleration does not "register 0 to 60". That isn't what acceleration is. It isn't speed; it's the *rate of change* in speed. Is this a Lamborghini or a VW Bug? They both go 0 to 60 but the acceleration might be very, very different.

  You might need to read a little physics textbook here, but to make it simple, think of it as how hard you are being pressed back against the car seat! If you are not being pressed back, thrown from side to side, etc., then your horizontal acceleration is zero even you are going 100 miles per hour.

Comment: Matt, I understand your points.  Thinking of horizontal motion, my iPhone (resting on the table) is reading about 0.005 on the Y axis.  So if the accelerometer is reading "acceleration" this number should change until I reach a constant speed where it should go back to equilibrium around 0.005.  Now if its measuring motion, the numbers should stay at some greater value, even during the constant speed, until the iPhone returns to a speed of zero where the value will go back to 0.005 since the iPhone is at rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following links can clarify what the accelerometer of the iPhone does, and does not:

> http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/iphone-accelerometer.htm
>
> http://www.engadget.com/2012/05/22/the-engineer-guy-shows-how-a-smartphone-accelerometer-works/